# JSP Include - Remove white space/new line

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, sitemesh

I'm trying to minify HTML in one line. For now I am using Sitemesh 3 filter and Htmlcompressor taglib but the problem is that when I import CSS files each file ends with new line so my HTML is not in one line.

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://htmlcompressor.googlecode.com/taglib/compressor" prefix="compress" %>
<compress:html enabled="true" removeComments="true" compressJavaScript="true">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><sitemesh:write property='title' /></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            <jsp:include page="/static/css/master.css"/>
            <jsp:include page="/static/css/header.css"/>
        </style>
```

So, the output HTML is compressed all except CSS inside style tag. Instead of puting all in one line the output is split (each css on new line).

Does anyone knows how to remove those whitespaces so I can have all in one line?

Comment: You probably want to use <compress:css> on the CSS files to compress them.